# Read more read less functionality for mobile view only

Tags: javascript

I am using read more / read less functionality one of my page, function is performing for desktop and mobile views but I want only for mobile view @media only screen and (max-width:550px), below my current used code.Please help...

```js
function AddReadMore() {

  var carLmt = 460;
  var readMoreTxt = " ... Read More";
  var readLessTxt = " Read Less";


  $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
      return;
    var allstr = $(this).text();
    if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
      var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
      var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
      var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
      $(this).html(strtoadd);
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
    $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
  });
}
$(function() {
  AddReadMore();
});
```

```css
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: #2ab1ce;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="addReadMore showlesscontent"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam </p>
```

Comment: A quick fix is to wrap the code that sets up the functionality in `if (window.innerWidth <= 550)`

Answer (score 2):

First: I found two issues:

- your click listener should be added directly to the buttons `$(".readMore, .readLess").on("click", function() {`
- for your example the char limit should be smaller than 460 since the example string has only ~160 chars, maybe `var carLmt = 60;`

---

You can achieve the media-query-like solution with an additional condition in your string-length-if:

```
if (allstr.length > carLmt && window.innerWidth <= 550) {
```

Since it should also work on resize you need a second event listener. In the attached handler you have to reset the paragraphs and call `AddReadMore()` again. For reseting you first have to delete the two buttons (remove the click-listener before), then grab the inner text of each parargaph and last overwrite with it the old paragraph content for deleting the `<span class='SecSec'>`.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $(".readMore, .readLess").off("click").remove();
    $('.addReadMore').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).text());
    });
    
    AddReadMore();
});
```

**Working example** (*resize the window to see the effect*):

```js
function AddReadMore() {

  var carLmt = 60;
  var readMoreTxt = " ... Read More";
  var readLessTxt = " Read Less";


  $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
      return;
    var allstr = $(this).text();
    if (allstr.length > carLmt && window.innerWidth <= 550) {
      var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
      var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
      var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
      $(this).html(strtoadd);
    }
  });

  $(".readMore, .readLess").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
  });
  
}

$(function() {
  AddReadMore();
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $(".readMore, .readLess").off("click").remove();
    $('.addReadMore').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).text());
    });
    
    AddReadMore();
});
```

```css
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: #2ab1ce;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="addReadMore showlesscontent"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam </p>
```

---

By the way, there are some things that i would make different (optional):

- since there is no `.firstSec` in your example delete the first if
- declare the whole buttons as extra vars for readability instead of just their inner text
- wrap the whole code in the document ready function

**Working example**:

```js
$(function() {

  function AddReadMore() {
    var carLmt = 60;
    var readMore = "<span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'> ... Read More</span>";
    var readLess = "<span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'> Read Less</span>";

    $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
      var allstr = $(this).text();

      if (allstr.length > carLmt && window.innerWidth <= 550) {
        var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
        var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
        var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span>" + readMore + readLess;

        $(this).html(strtoadd);
      }
    });

    $(".readMore, .readLess").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
    });
  }

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $(".readMore, .readLess").off("click").remove();
    $('.addReadMore').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).text());
    });

    AddReadMore();
  });

  AddReadMore();

});
```

```css
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: #2ab1ce;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="addReadMore showlesscontent"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam </p>
```